# Является ли map-getter лишней сущностью?

Tags: css3, html5, sass, scss

Есть такой `SCSS` код:

```
$font-weights: (
  "font-weight-thin": 100,
  "font-weight-light": 300,
  "font-weight-regular": 400,
  "font-weight-medium": 500,
  "font-weight-bold": 700,
  "font-weight-black": 900,
);

@function font-weight($font-weight-style){
 @return map-get($font-weights, $font-weight-style);
}
```

Далее его можем использовать в виде следующего вызова функции:

```
.header_top_navigation{
  font-weight: font-weight(font-weight-regular);
}
```

Вопрос: 
Что дает(какие преимущества и какие задачи решает) данный подход по сравнению с использованием обычных `SCSS` переменных?
Или же это просто альтернатива равнозначная но с более нагроможденный синтаксисом?